# Raster extent issue in R

Tags: raster, r

So, I have two different `rasters`, and I am trying to match their extent, even though the difference in their existing extents is quite small, but still `raster::stack` won't stack which is understandable. But, when I use the `crop` function to crop one raster on the basis of the other raster's extent, their extents still don't match up i.e., `xmax` of `rast1` doesn't change from `757322.8` to `757322.7`. . How can I solve this problem, when the purpose of stacking them together to compute standard deviation? I also tried using the `raster::extend` function but that is giving me a memory error.

```
library(raster)  
rast1 = raster::brick("path/rast1.tif")

rast2 = raster::brick("path/rast2.tif")

# Get the extent 
extent(rast1)

class      : Extent 
xmin       : 756472.2 
xmax       : 757322.8 
ymin       : 4074670 
ymax       : 4074953 

extent(rast2)

class      : Extent 
xmin       : 756472.2 
xmax       : 757322.7 
ymin       : 4074670 
ymax       : 4074953 

extent_1 = c(756472.2 ,4074670 ,757322.7 ,4074953)
rast1_Crop = crop(rast1, extent_1)
stack = raster::stack(rast1_Crop , rast_2)
```

Error

```
Error in compareRaster(x) : different extent
```

Comment: You must warp one image to match the extent and pixel size of the other. I do not know how to do that with r. Myself I would use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html with well selected `-te` and `-tr` parameters. Warping leads to resampling and it may alter the pixel values but with your data that should not happen with nearest neighbor resampling because pixels will be only slightly shifted.

Comment: Both of the rasters have the same pixel size and CRS.

Comment: I meant that pixel size and extent must both match. In your case warping would effectively slide one image to share the same xmin and xmax. Cropping selects pixels without altering them in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`crop` can only cut entire cells (rows, columns) so that won't help you here.

If you want to ignore the small difference, and the rasters have the same number of rows and columns, you can do

```
library(raster)
r1 = raster::brick("path/rast1.tif")
r2 = raster::brick("path/rast2.tif")
extent(r2) <- extent(r1)
s <- stack(r1, r2)
```

That is not generally a good idea; but given the very small difference it would seem OK here. And it is very efficient.

More generally, you can resample one raster to the structure of another like this

```
library(raster)
r1 = raster::brick("path/rast1.tif")
r2 = raster::brick("path/rast2.tif")
r1 <- resample(r1, r2)
s <- stack(r1, r2)
```

For better speed with `resample`, use `terra` instead

```
library(terra)
r1 = rast("path/rast1.tif")
r2 = rast("path/rast2.tif")
r1 <- resample(r1, r2)
s <- c(r1, r2)
```

And likewise you could do

```
r1 = rast("path/rast1.tif")
r2 = rast("path/rast2.tif")
ext(r1) <- ext(r2)
s <- c(r1, r2)
```

Comment: On a side note, can you please suggest `spatial statistics` packages in `R` that are compatible with `terra` raster objects?

Comment: That is a very broad topic. If you can be more specific about a particular type of analysis, then perhaps ask as question (not a comment). `terra` is new and there are not many other packages yet that extend it, but that does not mean they are not compatible; e.g. `gstat` is compatible (see `?terra::interpolate`).

Comment: I survived using resamble function of ```terra```